# How to create inifinite scroll on a CellTable in GWT?

Tags: gwt

How can I create a GWT Cell table with infinite scroll? I am looking for an answer which can work similar to the DZone front page, where the user can use the mouse or keyboard to scroll. Is this even possible with GWT may be a sub question.

Comment: Have you looked at http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellList ?

Comment: Yes, I did look at the showcase. You are right, it shows the problem, as the cell list supports infinite scrolling, but the cell table and data grid controls do not.

Comment: It's not the `CellList` that supports infinite scrolling. Look at the source code (hint: click on “Source code” and/or select `ShowMorePagerPanel.java` in the dropdown next to it)

Comment: Ah, I see, I didn't realise it allows selection of the source file. Thanks - I'm investigating this now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i dont think they do infinite scroll, it seems more like after you scroll to bottom of panel, more data is being added.

how to achieve sth like that in GWT? For start i think you should look at [ScrollEvent](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/ScrollEvent.html), capture event, end try scrolling position from it